# upload a csv file into cassandra (syntax error)

Tags: python, csv, cassandra

i am trying to upload a csv file to cassandra but I get the following error. I have already created my keyspace and table. I am only trying to upload the csv file now.

```
copy youtube(video_id, trending_date, title, channel_title, category_id, publish_time, tags, views, likes, dislikes, comment_count, comments_disabled, rating_disabled, video_error_or_removed) from ‘youtube.csv’ with  header=true;
```

the error is with the path. I have also used the following:

```
copy youtube (video_id, trending_date, title, channel_title, category_id, publish_time, tags, views, likes, dislikes, comment_count, comments_disabled, rating_disabled, video_error_or_removed) from ‘/Users/Keniajc93/Desktop/youtube.csv’ with = header=TRUE;
```

Could someone please help me?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/790XD.png)
  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOgUE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based off of what I can see, unless something was formatted during pasting, it looks like your quotation marks around the path are the "fancy" kind, not the straight ticks that it would expect. This can happen if you copy the text from something like MS Word. Maybe want to check that out.

Comment: Thank you. I just checked and I got the same error. :(

Comment: @KeniaCevallos Whatever that was suggested by Jim is true. The image that you provided clearly shows it. Image 1 at char 198 and Image 2 at char 199 both states you are using something different that single quote " ' ". Please edit it with single quote while you are running the command it will work cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested 
you may want to retype

```
‘youtube.csv’ to 'youtube.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

try using to use this command

copy table_name(all column names) from 'path/to/file/file_name.csv' with header = False;

columns names should be same in csv file and in cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like both of your queries have syntax problems some of them are highlighted by others already like absolute file path in the first query and "with = header=TRUE;" in second query and quotes in both of them.

You can try this:

copy youtube (video_id, trending_date, title, channel_title, category_id, publish_time, tags, views, likes, dislikes, comment_count, comments_disabled, rating_disabled, video_error_or_removed) from '/Users/Keniajc93/Desktop/youtube.csv' with header=TRUE;

Hope it helps.